# How to update state in Context using Hooks in MERN Stack Application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mern

I'm trying to find a way to update my "user" state, but I'm stuck here for 3 days already, I need some help.

Here is my user context:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

export const UserContext = React.createContext({})
const UserProvider = UserContext.Provider;

const UserContextProvider = (props) => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState({})
    
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(`${API}/auth/user`, {
            method: 'GET',
            withCredentials: true,
            credentials: 'include'
        })
        .then (response => response.json())
        .then (response => {
            setUser(response.user)
        })
        .catch (error => {
            console.error (error);
        });
    }, [setUser])

    console.log(user)

    return (
        <UserProvider value={{user, setUser}}>
            {props.children}
        </UserProvider>
    )
}   

export default UserContextProvider;
```

Here is where I'm trying to update the user. In my case I'm trying to push an object in user.cart array, cuz everything on the back-end is fine, but in the front-end the state is not updating:

- First I'm using the UserContext:

  const Products = () => {

  ```
         const {user, setUser} = useContext(UserContext) ...
  ```

And then here I'm trying to update the user state, BUT when I click the button it logged me out:

```
<button className="addTo--Cart--Button--Container">
      <FaShoppingCart onClick={() => {addToCart(user._id, product); setUser(oldState => oldState.cart.push(product))}}/>
</button>
```

After this logged me out, the `console.log(user)` which is in UserContextProvider function log only the user.cart updated lenght.

AND one more:

How to remove item from context:

Here is my remove function:

```
const removeFromContextCart = (id) => {
        console.log(id)
        const updatedCart = user.cart.filter((item) => item.id !== id);
        setUser(oldState => ({
            ...oldState,
            cart: [
                ...oldState.cart,
                updatedCart
            ]
        }))
    }
```

And my button:

```
<button className="remove--Button" onClick={() => {removeFromCart(user._id, product); setUser(removeFromContextCart(product._id))}}> REMOVE</button>
```

Comment: `setUser(oldState => oldState.cart.push(product))`, this mutates the original array, so react doesn't know if the state changed or not. Try returning a new object state

Comment: I understand that mutation, but how to do that with returning new object state ?

Comment: something like this?
`setUser(oldState => {
  const newCart = [...oldState.cart, product]
  return {...oldState, cart: newCart}
})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating the user state in this way

```
setUser(oldState => ({
  ...oldState,
  cart: [
    ...oldState.cart,
    product
  ]
}))
```

Comment: Thanks man! You save my life. I was trying for 3 days... :D

Comment: Could you check my updated question. How can I remove item from cart? My function isn't working for some reason. Thanks!